# jquery on beforeSubmit not called on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, stripe-payments

I've created a payment form with Stripe that needs to interact with their API in order to get a token before my form can be submitted. Everything was tested and working in Chrome, but yesterday a user said it's not working in Safari.

I've been able to narrow down the cause to Safari submitting the form before the following code is executed:

```
$('#payment-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {
                    if (isCcNeeded()) {

                        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
                        $('#payment-form').find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

                        // Request a token from Stripe:
                        Stripe.card.createToken({
                                number: $('input#stripe-card-number').val(),
                                cvc: $('input#stripe-cvc').val(),
                                exp_month: getExpMonth(),
                                exp_year: getExpYear(),
                                address_zip: $('input#stripe-address-zip').val()
                        }, stripeResponseHandler);

                        // Prevent the form from being submitted:
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Does anyone know why it's skipping this?

Comment: can you change beforeSubmit with submit and test?

Comment: Why are you calling beforeSubmit? Just use on submit and post the form in the stripeResponseHandler if the createToken call is successfull

Comment: @gaetanoM, I've tried it as well by replacing
$('#payment-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(event)
with
$('#payment-form').submit( function(event)
and also
$('#payment-form').on('submit', function(event)

both have the same result.

Comment: I'd second trying to use on 'submit' -- if you try something like this does it work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/30c9caj2/

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So the solution was actually a combination of a few things that I was trying. As the comments to my original post stated, I first needed to change to using 'submit' rather than 'beforeSubmit' (I think this is a Yii2 specific thing).

However, I had to take that one step further. In order for it to actually work, I had to also call preventDefault() on the event.

I also ended up migrating from stripe.js v2 to v3 while I was messing around with this code, so I'm not sure if that helped or not as well.

The final solution came to...

```
            var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
            $('#payment-form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                createToken();
            });
```

Thank you for the help everyone!